# Div fixed after scrolled

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day. I want to ask how do I change the distance from top of the window. Because the condition runs if the DIV reaches at the top. I want to have about 20 pixel distance from the top of the window before the condition runs.

Here is my sample JS: https://jsfiddle.net/o00kzsrb/1/

```
    function UpdateTableHeaders() {
        $(".panel").each(function() {
            var el         = $(this),
            offset         = el.offset(),
            scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
            floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

            if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.heigh())) {
                floatingHeader.css({
                    "visibility": "visible"
                });
            } else {
                floatingHeader.css({
                    "visibility": "hidden"
                });      
            };
            });
    }

    // DOM Ready      
    $(document ).ready(function() {
        var clonedHeaderRow;
        $(".panel").each(function() {
            clonedHeaderRow = $(".panel-heading", this);
            clonedHeaderRow
            .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
            .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
            .addClass("floatingHeader");

        });
        $(window)
        .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
        .trigger("scroll");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set the floatingHeader to visible 20px before it's panel would hit the top of the window. If you'd like it to be 20px after, change it to + 20.

```
    $(window).scroll(function (e){

        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        $(".panel").each(function() {

            var el         = $(this),
            offset         = el.offset(),
            floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", el);

            var visibility = scrollTop > (offset.top - 20)
                             && scrollTop < offset.top + el.height()?
                             "visible" : "hidden";

            floatingHeader.css({"visibility": visibility});

        });
    });
```

Comment: Do I need to erase the condition inside the function UpdateTableHeader if I insert your code??

Comment: Also, you may want to make some additional optimizations like pulling the scrollTop variable outside of the each (it's not going to change) and passing el instead of this as the context argument seeing as this function will be firing a lot.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking now. Do you want the .floatingHeader visible when its containing .panel is 20px below the top of the window or the user has scrolled 20px into the panel?

Comment: Ok. My answer should work for what you're looking for then.